# HTTP GET requests work but POST requests do not

Tags: spring, tomcat, networking

Our Spring application is running on several different servers.  For one of those servers POST requests do not seem to be working.  All site functionality that uses GET requests works completely fine;  however, as soon as I hit something that uses a POST request (ex. form submit) the site just hangs permanently.  The server won't give any response.  We can see the requests in Tomcat Manager but they don't time out.

Has anyone ever seen this?

Comment: It is very difficult to identify the cause of the error from the given piece of information. Post some code. Post your debugging inferences. What works, what does not, where it fails. Any specific scenarios where it fails, etc.

Comment: @gotuskar Think about it, what code would I post?  Everything is fine on my local and fine on all production servers except the one I am referencing.  I can't paste the entire project here.  Also, I mentioned that GET requests work and POST requests do not.  I wish I could be more specific but this is all I can observe.

Comment: Do you have a WebServer or do you go directly to Tomcat ?

Comment: Then that production machine has some issues. That's all I can infer. Sure, you cannot post your code. Thats why I also asked for debug information. Any side effects, uncertainties you see? What if that bad production machine is removed from cluster, do all requests work fine? What if that bad production machine is the only machine in your cluster, all good ones are removed, does every POST request fail?

Comment: @ben75 I'm sorry, I am not exactly sure what you mean.  The server having the issues is a Linux box running Tomcat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have found the problem.  Our DBA accidentally deleted the MySQL database files on that particular server (/sigh).  In our Spring application we use GET requests for record retrieval and the records we were trying to retrieve must have been cached by MySQL.  This made it seem as if GET requests were working.  When trying to add new data to the database, which we use POST requests to do, Tomcat would wait for a response, which never came, from MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience if you're getting a timeout error it's almost always due to not having correct ports open for your application. For example, go into your virtual machine's rules and insure port 8080, 8443 or 80, 443 are open for http and https traffic.
In google cloud platform: its under VPC networking -> firewall rules. Azure and AWS are  similar.